# Running a Python script locally from a command sent using NextJS webserver

Tags: python, nginx, next.js

I have a website built in NextJS. I also have a local Python script I run on a different server. The Python script, for many reasons, cannot be run on the website webserver. Right now I manually run the Python script based on some information from the website.

I want to automate this by essentially allowing the website to trigger the python script to run on the other machine. I don't know how to go about doing this. Does such a mechanism exist? What protocol or way should I go about doing this?

I was thinking that I would need to setup a webserver on the Python server that would just 'listen', then the website server would send a command to the Python server to initiate that the Python script needs to be run. The problem now is how does the Python NextJS server send a command to Python to actually run the script??

Comment: sounds good. Python has a few options for api-servers, e.g. fastapi, with good documentation...

Comment: @thebjorn so the only solution is to actually change the Python? I can't write some NextJS code to actually trigger the python script to run?

Comment: You want one machine to start a script on another machine directly... You could try psexec or wmi (if on windows), or ssh (if on *nix), but there are security consequences...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and it is relatively easy to setup as a full stack web app inside a single Next.js project.

There is some documentation from Vercel themselves (creators of Next.js) which describe how this can be achieved with Next.js as a frontend and Python Web Framework (e.g. Django, Flask, FastAPI) as the backend, where both can be hosted within the same single Next.js full stack project app.

So you should be able to import from, access, and run your Python scripts from within a single Next.js project, from within the backend api server directories (or possibly alternatively from custom backend related directories that you may wish to create outside of the api server directory, e.g. from the project root).

#### Vercel documentation, GitHub sample projects, and hosted demos

Documentation links for setting up combined Next.js frontend and Python API backend servers in a single project, provided below:

- [Next.js FastAPI Starter](https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/nextjs-fastapi-starter) - with example source code from [GitHub repository](https://github.com/digitros/nextjs-fastapi), and a Vercel hosted demonstration of the Python [API response](https://nextjs-fastapi-starter.vercel.app/api/python)
- [Next.js Flask Starter](https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/nextjs-flask-starter) - with example source code from [Github repository](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/python/nextjs-flask), and a Vercel hosted demonstration of the Python [API response](https://nextjs-flask-starter.vercel.app/api/python).
- [Using the Python Runtime with Serverless Functions](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes/python)

#### Example Code Snippets

The key takeaway essential code snippets (provided below) are taken from the above documentation links and from a sample working project hosted on a Next.js [GitHub project](https://github.com/digitros/nextjs-fastapi/) with a Python FastAPI web server backend. The sample full stack app is hosted on Vercel, where you can view the [JSON response](https://nextjs-fastapi-starter.vercel.app/api/python) from the Python backend.

The following code snippets below assumes you already have Node.js, and Python installed on your system, and also a Next.js project scaffolded / setup.

1. Firstly it is generally recommended to create and activate the Python virtual environment within the project (e.g. `pip -m venv env` or `virtualenv -p python` or `pipenv shell`), that way you isolate the dependencies that will be installed in later steps, to the project only, rather than installing dependencies on your global OS Python environment.
2. Create a Python `requirements.txt` in the root of the project with the dependencies of your preferred Python Web Framework of choice. In this example, I'm using FastAPI (versions specified in example are sure to be outdated in future, so use the latest stable versions where possible):

```
fastapi==0.100.1
uvicorn[standard]==0.23.2
```

3. In your terminal, and from the root of the project, install the listed Python dependencies from the `requirements.txt` file. Ensure that your terminal session is within an activated virtual Python environment (see step 1), to isolate the dependencies to the project only, so as to avoid installing dependencies at the global OS level.

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

4. Update the project root `next.config.js` file to rewrite the mapping of the standard Next.js api routes to point to the Python web api server (and matching paths) on development, or to a directory which will host the python web server once deployed.

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  rewrites: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
            ? "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/:path*"
            : "/api/",
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

5. Create a simple Python (FastAPI) `GET` route handler for the endpoint `/api/python`, under the example file `/api/index.py`:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/api/python")
def hello_world():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

6. Update the `package.json` file located located within the root of the project, with a script to concurrently run both the Next.js frontend and Python backend server, where `fastapi-dev` will run the python backend FastAPI server, and `next-dev` will run the frontend client web server, and `dev` gives you the option to run both servers concurrently, although you would need to also install a separate npm dependency `concurrently` to successfully run both servers at once with the `dev` command (e.g. `npm run dev`):

```json
{
  "name": "nextjs-fastapi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "fastapi-dev": "pip3 install -r requirements.txt && python3 -m uvicorn api.index:app --reload",
    "next-dev": "next dev",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run next-dev\" \"npm run fastapi-dev\"",
    ...
  },
}
```

7. From the CLI / terminal / shell, and with the current working directory set to the root of the project, run the Next.js frontend and Python backend servers with the following command:

```bash
npm run dev
```

8. Once both the frontend and backend servers are served and ready, open the browser, and navigate to the given frontend server URL provided from the running CLI / terminal output (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/`), and you should be able to test a working Python backend API JSON response from there (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/api/python`)

If you're still having trouble, then please refer to the Vercel documentation and GitHub repository links provided above.

#### Special Considerations

I believe such a setup would currently work for Next.js apps that are hosted on the **Vercel** platform, as Vercel hosts serverless functions for Python runtimes (currently in [Beta](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes/python) as of 25th August 2023). Maybe other platforms (will) support this approach too.